# What is the most efficient way to get full row data from MySQL when using Sphinx?

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I am trying to use MySQL with Sphinx to provide fulltext searching on usernames in order to provide a user search/autocomplete feature.

I have everything set up using the sphinx php api and have managed to get a list of userid's returned with this code:

```
include('/usr/local/lib/php/sphinxapi.php');

  $sphinx = new \SphinxClient();
  $mysqlconn = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:9306") or die ("Couldn't connect to MySQL.");
  $results = $sphinx->Query("John", "users");

  $ids = "";
        foreach($results['matches'] as $id => $data) {
             if($ids > ""){
                     $ids .= ",";
             }
            $ids .= $id;
        }


    echo json_encode($ids);
```

This returns a comma seperated list of userid's which have the word 'John' in eitheer their firstname or lastname column

Taking this approach I would now need to query the actual mysql database and pull out the users matching those ID's.

My question is what would be the most efficient way of doing this?  Should I use a simple select with an `IN()` clause or is there a far better way?

Also can Sphinx not return this data for me itself automatically in a more efficient manner?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, querying again the mysql database separately is required when using sphinx... You looking up a key in one db and then using it in another DB. No way around it--sort of like using the yellow pages to find a phone number, you still have to dial the number on your phone to speak to the person.  There is no way to construct a join across the two DB's (outside of writing a wrapper library to make it look like it's doing so).

However....

An option you have is to convert your DB over to MariaDB (a drop in replacement for MySQL).  As of 5.2.2 they have integration with sphinx as a storage engine: https://kb.askmonty.org/en/about-sphinxse/2941/

Comment: Interesting... +1 for MariaDB suggestion, I'll look into that.  If we were to stick with MYSQL for our users table would an IN() search be the most optimal way of retrieving the data bearing in mind it will be retrieved live as the user is typing into an input element.

Comment: @gordyr MariaDB also has a bunch of optimizations like no penalty for using inner selects, group commits, and better thread pooling.

Comment: @gordyr `IN` is fine.  If the columns being search for are indexed it's like having a bunch of straight comparisons... you want to avoid a separate query each item with multiple results returned from sphinx... if the column is indexed you'll pay more for processing each new requests.  With `IN` it will all be a in single query--much more efficient.

Comment: Fab... Thanks Ray your help is much appreciated

Comment: You dont need to use MariaDB, to use SphinxSE. Can use it with vanilla MySQL. Although it can be hard to get it working depending on your server version. MariaDB just provides prepackaged. Not that sphinxSE wont in general give you much purely performance benefit. It does the same thing under the hood, mostly it brings convenience.

Comment: Why would querying another DB be required when ushing Sphinx? If you set sql_field_string Sphinx can even return strings (not available before 2.0 but I might be wrong on version number)

Answer (score 1):

This is the first question on the Sphinx FAQ page :)

http://sphinxsearch.com/info/faq/#row-storage

Although I usually find it more effienct to do the 'sorting' in the application, rather than in mysql. Using associtive arrays, can avoid the sort phase altogether. Example using that technique here:
http://www.nearby.org.uk/sphinx/search-example5-withcomments.phps

Comment: Thanks Barry, I had already read that, however I wanted to know if there was a more efficient way since using sphinx from the console returns the whole row data.  I figured there might be some way of using this.

Comment: Ignore the console search toy. It does it in the worse way possible. Issues a sepeate query (the sql_query_info from the config file) for every document separately. Really, forget you ever found the the 'search' binary, your life with sphinx will be so much better.

Comment: Wowsers! a separate select for every id? Huge thanks for the info, you've probably saved me several hours of wasted time. :)